# Why complexity of linear function is same as that of quadratic equation

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, time-complexity

I am learning algorithms.. So, I came along with something very interesting.

The asymptotic bound of linear equation ( `(a*n)+b` ) is `O(n^2)`.. for all **`a>0.`**

This is same that of not so surprising.. `a* n^2 + b* n + c`

Why?

Comment: Um, this is certainly an asymptotic *upper bound*, yes... But it's not the tightest asymptotic bound, which is a much more interesting result.

Comment: where did you hear this?

Comment: Even n^3 is an upper bound on first. however, the tighter one is O(n) which is not the case for second one

Comment: This is like saying: My datsun (linear) costs less than $1 million while His Ferrari (quadratic) costs less than $1 million as well (for some Ferrari's anyway)  :P

Comment: This is from Introduction to Algorithms by Thomas H. Cormen

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because [big-oh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) gives you an upper bound. Your first function is also `O(n^3), O(n^4), O(n^2012)` etc.

The definition of big-oh basically says that `f(n) is O(g(n))` if there exists some `k` such that, for all `n > k`, we have `g(n) > f(n)`.

Look into [big-theta](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_theta#Family_of_Bachmann.E2.80.93Landau_notations) for stronger / tight bounds.

Comment: when an + b  there is a constant c = a + b/n_0 where 0 <= an + b <= cn. am I right??